# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID when including JS file in Laravel welcome page (using Laravel Sail)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, alpine.js

I'm trying to include a JavaScript file in the welcome page of my Laravel application, but I'm encountering an error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

I have followed the standard procedure of including a JavaScript file, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code snippet from my welcome page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

     @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</head>
<body class="antialiased">

    <div x-data="{ count: 0 }">
        <button x-on:click="count++">Increment</button>
     
        <span x-text="count"></span>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here's the code snippet from my `app.js`:

```
import './bootstrap';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs'

window.Alpine = Alpine

Alpine.start()
```

I have placed the `app.js` file in the `resources/js` directory, as is customary in Laravel.

I have verified that the file path is correct, and the `app.js` file exists in the specified location. I also made sure that the Laravel development server is running when accessing the welcome page.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the resulting HTML snippet that is added when you use `@vite`. Also, have in mind that you must be running `npm run dev` INSIDE the container, not outside, are you doing so?

Comment: Yes `npm run dev` is running inside the container `sail@15684f559b8f:/var/www/html$` . This is the resulting HTML  snippets 
<script type="module" src="0.0.0.0:5173/@vite/client"></script>
<script type="module" src="http://0.0.0.0:5173/resources/js/app.js"></script>